# Why can dogs hyperventilate without consequences like humans?

Tags: human-biology, zoology

During the heat of summer, dogs usually breathes very fast, like 100 times per minute or more. If humans do so, we will experience an array of negative effects like dizziness, finger tingling or losing consciousness, by the results of blood alkalosis and reduced oxygen level. The question is, why don't our canine buddies seem to experience the same consequences?